# When using runTransaction, I got permission denied

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing chat system, calculating total unread count.

here's my code

```
        chatroomRef.child(chatInfo.getPartner_firebase_uid())
            .child(mChatId)
            .child("totalUnreadCount")
            .runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                @Override
                public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                    Integer totalUnreadCount = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);
                    if(totalUnreadCount == null){
                        mutableData.setValue(0);
                    }else{
                        mutableData.setValue(totalUnreadCount + 1);
                    }
                    return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Log.d("result", "postTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
                }
            });
```

When used this code, I got permission denied.
But when I used code below, it worked.

```
chatroomRef.child(chatInfo.getPartner_firebase_uid())
                        .child(mChatId)
                        .child("totalUnreadCount")
                        .setValue(1);
```

two codes set data change exactly same course in firebase-db.
Though one code gets permission error, the other doesn't.
So I think it is a problem with firebase rules.
And, I gave 'true' to '.write', but got permission error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have permission to **read** the value of `totalUnreadCount`. A transaction writes a new value based on the existing value, so it needs both read and write permission.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know how to accept an answer. Now I learned it!